# How to insert selected radio button value into table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" id="rating">1
<input type="radio" id="rating2">2
<input type="radio" id="rating3">3
<input type="radio" id="rating4">4
<input type="radio" id="rating5">5
```

I have one table

```
<table id="myTableData"  border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr id="templateRow">
            <th>Ratings</th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

One add button

```
 <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="addRadioValue()">
```

I've written the code to dynamically add rows to the table, but when I select a radio button and then I click on the add button, the value of the selected radio button should get inserted into a new cell within table Ratings.

I am able do this thing for a text box, but I'm not able to do it for a radio button.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: show your whole code and html

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create Demo

Comment: Your radio buttons don't have values at the moment. Add a value. `<input type="radio" id="rating" value="rating">1`

Comment: Here is jsfiddle link   [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PravinKottawar/cv4u0nf9/)

Comment: You need the javascript to load in the head for your jsfiddle for it to work

Comment: Code is working fine for me only issue is for 2nd time radio button is not getting deselected . I want every time radio button should be refreshed. I am also not getting how to handle multiple radio button

Comment: You need the `name` attribute set on the radios for them to be deselected when another is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems were that you didn't have `name` set on the radios and that you were trying to grab the selected radio with a get id statement. You actually need to grab the radio elements by name and do a loop to check which is selected.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cv4u0nf9/4/

The loop i inserted

```
var ratings = document.getElementsByName("rating");
for (var i=0; i<ratings.length; i++) {
    if (ratings[i].checked) {
        rating = ratings[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `querySelector('input[name="rating"]:checked')`

**Java script**

```
function addRow() {

    var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var auther = document.getElementById("auther");
    var publish = document.getElementById("publish");
    var rating = document.querySelector('input[name="rating"]:checked');
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML=count ;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= auther.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= publish.value;
    if(rating.checked)
        row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= rating.value;
    else
        row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= "";
    count=count+1;
}
```

Here is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cv4u0nf9/6/)